# How to redirect index to index.php? (with .htaccess)

Tags: php, .htaccess

But I also want that every page redirect to page.php for example:

me -> me.php

blog -> blog.php

test -> test.php

I don't know if redirect is the right word because what I want is that we call X and it open X.php but don't show the extension (.php)

Hope everybody can help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a `.htaccess` file and put this in it:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

That way, URLs such as `domain.com/blog`, it will silently append `.php` to the file name (ie loading `blog.php`).

Comment: @João Plus `Don't work` says nothing. Explain why it doesn't work, please. Did you get an error, the rule was not applied, what?

Comment: The rule was not applied. I did what Supericy said but when try to go to index it doesn't show the file index.php. The error is the usual 404.